# Proof that the composition of two monoid homomorphisms is a monoid homomorphism.

Tags: proof-verification, monoid

Let *f* : *M* → *N* and *g* : *N* → *K* be monoid homomorphisms. I tried to prove that *g* ∘ *f* : *M* → *K* is a monoid homomorphism too.

Let m,m' ∈ M then,

(g ∘ f) (mm') = g (f (mm'))

= g (f (m) f (m'))

= g (f (m)) g (f (m'))

= (g ∘ f) (m) (g ∘ f) (m')

Is that correct?

Comment: Just for balance,you might want to add a $g(f(m))g(f(m'))$ line.

Comment: It is okay on its own, but not enough. It must also be shown that $g\circ f$ respects the identity. When we are dealing with monoids then that is not a consequence of respecting multiplication (as it is in groups). This finds its cause in the fact that in a monoid there can be more than $1$ idempotent element.

Comment: Proof in "Finite-State Techniques: Automata, Transducers and Bimachines" p19